# case statement in sql with multiple joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I had 2 tables joining together and returning what I wanted with:

```
SELECT a, b, table_one.c, d, e 
from table_one INNER JOIN table_two ON table_two.c=table_one.d 
WHERE table_two.c
```

I have a third table, table_three, that also has column c. I need a column with a flag (like a boolean) of whether or not the the value appears in the third table.
I've been trying to do a case statement and a left join for this but I can't figure out the syntax.

I know I could put the case as another column after the SELECT, something like:

```
SELECT a, b, table_one.c, d, e
     , case table_three.c 
           when table_three.other_column_in_table_three ISNULL THEN true           
           ELSE false 
       END 
from table_one INNER JOIN....
```

But I'm not sure if that's quite right and I have no idea how to add a left join onto this query. Is this the right idea and, if so, how does the syntax work?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Case expression, not case statement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler approach

```
select a, b, table_one.c, d, e
     , table_three.other_column is not null as flag
from table_one inner join table_two on table_one.d = table_two.c
     left join table_three on -- put here the relation rules between table_three
                              -- and the other tables
```

Comment: so for relation rules between table 3, I think that should just be:     table_three.c=table_one.d      ---just like joining table_one and table_two
but what do I need for "and the other tables"?

Answer (score 1):

In MSSQL you could try:

```
SELECT a, b, table_one.c, d, e, ISNULL(table_three.c, true)
from table_one
INNER JOIN table_two ON table_two.c = table_one.d
LEFT JOIN table_three ON table_two.c = table_three.c
```